# Catch text block between 2 regex

Tags: python, regex, text, python-3.x

First I've to tell you that I'm working on Python 3.3.

I'm starting with python and regex and I would like to know how to catch a text bloc from a *.txt* file between 2 regex.

Here is an example of what I have in my file :

```
    commit 1f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a79
    this is
    commit 1
    bloc

    commit 2f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a78
    this is
    commit 2

    bloc

    commit 3f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a77
    this is

    commit 3


    bloc

    commit 4f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a76

    this is
    commit 
    4
    bloc
```

So I would like to catch the text between 2 regex starting by `commit` AND follewed by a space and 40 charaters (I guess this is : `^commit.{41}`).
N.B. A line just starting by `commit` and nothing behind shouldn't work.
And of course, I've to be able to get the last commit block. It won't end by a `commit.{41}` but by the end of the file.

Once I've all blocks, I've to be able to work on it. Here is what a `git log -p` looks like

```
commit 1f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a79
Merge: 4e1d5f7 8ffg9do
Author: name <email>
Date:   date of commit

    "comment 
    of the commit
    on multilines"

diff --…
index …
--- …
+++ …
@@ …
-…
+…
 …

diff --…
index …
--- …
+++ …
@@ …

commit 2f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a78
Author: name <email>
Date:   date
```

So for exemple, get `commitBlock[0]`. That would be :

```
Merge: 4e1d5f7 8ffg9do
Author: name <email>
Date:   date of commit

    "comment 
    of the commit
    on multilines"

diff --…
index …
--- …
+++ …
@@ …
-…
+…
 …

diff --…
index …
--- …
+++ …
@@ …
```

Extract `Author:` line (=`Author: name <email>`)

Extract the comment of the `commitBlock` :
    "comment 
    of the commit
    on multilines"

And same for `diffBlock`.

N.B. same as `commitBlock` , the `diffBlock` should stop when there is another `diff` or a `commit.{41}` or a `end of file`

---

I've tried few things :

Here is what I had before I realised I need to get multines blocks.

```
source = open("file.txt","rt", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

for line in source:

    commit = re.findall('^commit.{41}',line) #line starts with by "commit" and is followed by 41 characters
    merge = re.findall('^Merge:.*',line)
    author = re.findall('^Author:.*',line)
    date = re.findall('^Date:.*',line)
    signed = re.findall('Signed-off-by:.*', line)

    for commitLine in commit:
        print (commitLine)
        #post into DB

    for mergeLine in merge:
        print (mergeLine)
        #post into DB
    .
    .
    .
```

Or 
    re.findall('^commit.{41}(.*?)^commit.{41}| *endoffile*', source.read(), re.DOTALL|re.M)

I also tried to use `re.split()`. It works well for `commitBlock` ! But I've a problem when I want to split `diffBlock` and `commentBlock` because I'm supposed to use sometimes the `commit` line to stop the block. And it doesn't appear anymore because of the `split`.

```
import os
import re
from pymongo import Connection


source = open("testSelection.txt","r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") #file that we want to analyse
sourceRead = open("testSelection.txt","r", encoding="ISO-8859-1").read() #writing source.read() bugs...
print(source.name)


commit = []
for line in source:
    if line[:6]=="commit":
            commitId = line[7:]
            commit.append(line)

f=1
while f < len(commitBlock):
    lineCommitBlock = re.split('\n', commitBlock[f])
    diffBlock = re.split('\ndiff', commitBlock[f])
    print("-----------------------------NEW COMMIT BLOCK-------------------------------")
    print(commit[f-1])
    i=0
    while i < len(lineCommitBlock):
        if "Merge:" in lineCommitBlock[i]:
            print(lineCommitBlock[i])
        elif "Author:" in lineCommitBlock[i]:
            print(lineCommitBlock[i])
        elif "Date:" in lineCommitBlock[i]:
            print(lineCommitBlock[i])
        elif "Signed-off-by:" in lineCommitBlock[i]:
            print(lineCommitBlock[i])
        elif "Tested-by:" in lineCommitBlock[i]:
            print(lineCommitBlock[i])
        elif "Reviewed-by:" in lineCommitBlock[i]:
            print(lineCommitBlock[i])
        i += 1
    print("Before commentBlock <--------------------------------------------------------------------")

    print("Adter commentBlock <--------------------------------------------------------------------")
    j=1   
    while j < len(diffBlock):
        print(diffBlock[j])
        j += 1

    f += 1

source.close()
```

(I agree, it looks lie a mess !)

Any idea how to solve my problem ? Thanks !

---

EDIT : 
I almost finished my work, so I guess that would be faster for me to find the way to catch the commentBlock with regex or something else than using GitPython (that works with Python 2., not with 3. ...).
Can someone help me with this problem ?

All I need is to catch the text after the line starting by `Date:` and a `diff` or a `commit` or the end of the file.

I'm really stuck on this point...

Comment: You can use GitPython for that.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel when a tool already exists ! Thanks, I'll have a look. Just hope it's easy to use.

Comment: Btw, does GitPython works with python 3 ?
And I'm still curious to know what regex would have solved my problem.